# Workspace binding "ssh-directory" does not match any declared workspace

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, git-clone, tekton

I am trying to do task git-clone in Tekton pipeline to Gitlab. I have already installed the required pipeline and now I am trying to install Pipeline run but I am receiving an error.

Install pipeline run inside the Tekton pipeline using the git clone. My goal is to deploy source code from Gitlab to Tekton to OpenShift

Reference: https://Tekton.dev/docs/how-to-guides/clone-repository/#full-code-samples

Installed pipeline for Git clone -done
install Pipeline run for Git clone-pending

[image: error message]

my configuration of pipeline
[[image: pipeline]

Comment: Possibly related to [Propagating Workspaces to Referenced Tasks](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/taskruns/#propagating-workspaces-to-referenced-tasks).

Comment: Does it mean I need to install referenced task?

Comment: Not sure, I only mention it for you to investigate.

Comment: Share/check your TaskRun/PipelineRun & Tasks. The title for your thread suggests your tasks have a "ssh-directory" workspace, which is not set starting your run. And avoid  screenshots or link to third-party sites. Explain with your own words: what you did and what's happening. Now, if you need to authenticate cloning stuff, I wouldn't use a workspace, and rather follow this: https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/auth.md#configuring-authentication-for-git

Comment: The only problem is that whenever I am trying to execute clone-read task. But it seems "ssh-directory" workspace is missing. I just followed the guide from Tekton. I attached the current pipeline configuration for the clone-read. The only goal is to deploy source code from Gitlab to Tekton Pipeline